# Haskell's newtypes in Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, newtype

In Haskell we can declare newtypes to reduce dynamic memory allocations and create type-safe APIs.

```
newtype Username String = Username String
  deriving (Eq, Ord)
```

newtype works only with data types which have single constructor with single argument. Is there something similar to newtype in Scala?

Example:

```
case class Username(username: String)
```

for username we could've write something like this in Scala:

```
newtype Username(username: String)
```

Comment: Which Scala version?

Answer (score 4):

The equivalent to Haskell's [`newtype`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Newtype) are [*Opaque Type Aliases*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/types-opaque-types.html) in Scala 3:

```scala
opaque type Username = String
```

It's basically a `type` alias … but opaque. Just like it says on the cover.

Comment: Would it be worth mentioning that in **Scala 2** we can use this library: https://github.com/estatico/scala-newtype?

Comment: There's also value classes in Scala 2, isn't it?

Comment: @GaëlJ given their limitations and surprising behaviors I wouldn't recommend them for new type modeling.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: I pretend Scala 2 no longer exists. Makes the whole transition much more smooth: there is no transition :-D

Comment: @GaëlJ: I don't consider value classes to be opaque type wrappers. They are user-defined value types ("primitives" in Java-speak). Distinct use cases.